# Collection of subsets of a set with small overlap with each other

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a set with n elements. Consider a set S of subsets, each of fixed size k, with the property that any two subsets in S have intersection of size at most m-1 . 
In the following link

[Choosing subsets of a set with a specified amount of maximum overlap between them](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093/choosing-subsets-of-a-set-with-a-specified-amount-of-maximum-overlap-between-the)

it was mentioned that if $n>2k^2$, then there exists such a set S with size atleast $(\frac{n}{2k})^m$. Clearly this bound is not the best possible for $k=m$, since in that case, the correct answer is $n\choose m$, which is 
$\approx (\frac{n}{m})^m$, for large $n$.

So is there a better bound which holds for k close to m? Also is someone aware of references in literature, to these results?