# Extremal set theory problem concerning translations of a set of integers

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Let $A$ be a subset of $B = \{1, 2,\ldots,n\}$. Suppose that $F$ is a family of subsets of $B$, each of which is a translation of $A$ and no two of which intersect more than once. What is the maximum size of $F$?

This question is similar to the following question:
[Choosing subsets of a set with a specified amount of maximum overlap between them](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093/choosing-subsets-of-a-set-with-a-specified-amount-of-maximum-overlap-between-the?rq=1)

Can we improve the Ray-Chaudhuri-Wilson and Frankl Theorems if we know that each subset is a translation of some given subset?

Comment: Note proper MathJax code: $B = \{1, 2,\ldots,n\}$ is coded as B = \{1, 2,\ldots,n\}.  What was here was this: $\qquad$ $B$ = {$1, 2,...,n$}. The "equals" sign and the $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ did not match in font and in size and there was not proper spacing. $\qquad$