# Families of 3-element subsets such that no two intersect more than once

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Another user asked the following question:

"How can I determine the size of the largest collection of $k$-element subsets of an $n$-element set such that each pair of subsets has at most $m$ elements in common?"

Link: [Choosing subsets of a set with a specified amount of maximum overlap between them](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093/choosing-subsets-of-a-set-with-a-specified-amount-of-maximum-overlap-between-the?rq=1)

The top answer to this question gives upper and lower bounds. Has anyone calculated the exact solutions to this problem for small values of the parameters? In particular, I am interested in $k=3$, $m=1$, and various values of $n$. Is there a table of solutions available anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the [orchard-planting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchard-planting_problem).  But you'll want something so that every pair of points defines a three point line.  For that, you'll want a [finite projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometry).

For example, with 15 points, there is a [35 line projective space](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/15PointProjectiveSpace/).

These can be chosen as the triples from 1-15 with a BitXor sum of 0.

{1,2,3), (1,4,5), (1,6,7), (1,8,9), (1,10,11), (1,12,13),
(1,14,15), (2,4,6), (2,5,7), (2,8,10), (2,9,11), (2,12,14),
(2,13,15), (3,4,7), (3,5,6), (3,8,11), (3,9,10), (3,12,15),
(3,13,14), (4,8,12), (4,9,13), (4,10,14), (4,11,15), (5,8,13),
(5,9,12), (5,10,15), (5,11,14), (6,8,14), (6,9,15), (6,10,12),
(6,11,13), (7,8,15), (7,9,14), (7,10,13), (7,11,12)

With 81 points, you can play the Game of Set.  There are 1080 lines.