Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a set of subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ satisfying some conditions. Let $f$ be maximum $|\mathcal{F}|$. Prove $n^2-4n\le 6f\le n^2-n$
This is problem 9.104 from A path to combinatorics for undergraduates.
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a set of subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that
(i) every element in $\mathcal{F}$ is a three-element subset; and
(ii) the intersection of any two elements of $\mathcal{F}$ contains at most one element.
Let $f$ denote the maximum number of elements that $\mathcal{F}$ can have. Prove $n^2-4n\le 6f\le n^2-n$.
Here is my attempt
Denote $\{1,2,...,n\}$ by $[n]$. Suppose we have an $\mathcal{F}$ satisfying the above conditions. Let $|\mathcal{F}|=m$. Let $P_2([n])$ denote the set of $2$-elements subsets of $[n]$ and $\mathcal{F}=\{F_1,F_2,...,F_m\}$. Let $S=\{(a,F)\in P_2([n])\times\mathcal{F}|a\subseteq F\}$. For any $\{x,y\}\in P_2([n])$, we define $S(\{x,y\},\ast)=\{(\{x,y\},F)\in S| F\in \mathcal{F}\}$. For any $F_j\in\mathcal{F}$, we define $S(\ast,F_j)=\{(a,F_j)\in S| a\in P_2([n])\}$.
By Fubini's Principle, we have $\sum_{\{x,y\}\in P_2[n]}|S(\{x,y\},\ast)|=\sum_{F_j\in \mathcal{F}}|S(\ast,F_j)|=\sum_{F_j\in \mathcal{F}}\binom{3}{2}=3m$.
By condition (ii), for any $\{x,y\}\in P_2[n]$, $|S(\{x,y\},\ast)|\le 1$. (Otherwise, there would be two elements of $\mathcal{F}$ whose intersection contains more than one element.) So we have $\sum_{\{x,y\}\in P_2[n]}|S(\{x,y\},\ast)|\le\sum_{\{x,y\}\in P_2[n]}1=\binom{n}{2}$.
Combining the above, we get $3m\le \binom{n}{2}$. So we have $6f\le n^2-n$.
How can the lower bound be obtained?
There's a similar question here: Let $F$ be a set of subsets of the set $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ such that: but it's not the same since the lower bound on that question is different.

ah... Actually, the lower bound in your post is weaker then the post you have linked to.

Okay. But that question is not answered for all positive integers $n$.

After some offline work, it seems that the sequence $f(n)$ generated in this way is documented as OEIS entry A001839. But I don't know whether that helps with establishing the lower bound.

A similar question with more general conditions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093

An even better lower bound can be achieved by construction. Let $\mathcal F$ consist of the triples $\{x,y,z\}$ such that $n$ divides $x+y+z$. It satisfies the restriction because if $x+y+z_1$ and $x+y+z_2$ are both divisible by $n$, then so is their difference, i.e. $z_2-z_1 \equiv 0 \pmod n$ and because $1 \leq z_1,z_2 \leq n$, we must have $z_1 = z_2$.
Now let's count the size of this $\mathcal F$. It's easier to count the ordered triplets $(x,y,z)$ (with $x,y,z$ all distinct). And the factor $6=3!$ is already there to cancel.
So denote
$$
\mathcal X = \{(x,y,z) \in \{1,2,\dots, n\}^3 : x+y+z \equiv 0 \pmod n\}
$$
We use inclusion-exclusion using the sets
$$
A = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathcal X : x=y\} \\
B = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathcal X : x=z\} \\
C = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathcal X : y=z\}
$$
We have
$$
6|\mathcal F| = |\mathcal X| - |A| - |B| - |C| + |A\cap B| + |A\cap C| + |B \cap C| - |A\cap B \cap C|
$$
Notice $|\mathcal X| = n^2$ since $x$ and $y$ can be anything, then $z$ is unique by $x+y+z \equiv 0 \pmod n$. Further $|A| = |B| = |C| = n$ since we can pick any value for the repeated number and then the third one is unique. All the sets $A\cap B,  A\cap C, B \cap C, A\cap B \cap C$ are equal to the set $T:=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathcal X : x=y=z\}$.
So we get the lower bound
$$
6f \geq 6|\mathcal F| = n^2 - 3n + 2|T| \geq n^2 - 3n.
$$

Could you please explain what "two numbers can be same in $3$
ways" mean?

@19021605 I wrote it more formally now. What was meant previously was these 3 sets $A, B, C$.

Side note: $( n, n, n) \in T$ so $ |T| \geq 1$ so you've shown the stronger bound of $ \geq n^2 - 3n + 2$ as mentioned in the linked problem.
